# Making picture a link to

Tags: php, html

How can i make this picture a link using this coding format?

```
if($row['name'] !== "") { 
  echo "<br/><img src='../login/image/";
  echo $row['name'];
  echo "'  style='width: 300px;height: 400px;'>";
```

Comment: `<a href="link"><img src="image" /></a>` is work for a link with picture.

Comment: I tried that and the picture disappeared.

Comment: OK, where is your file path to your PHP file and where is the path to your Image? Is `$row['name']` your image file name? Can you `echo` it out?

Comment: You also forgot to close your image, end with /> not >. To make it a clickable link, you simply add an a href infront on the inage...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this, you also don't need all the `echo`s.

```
if($row['name'] !== "") { 
  echo "<br/><a href='link'><img src='../login/image/" . $row['name'] . "' style='width:300px; height:400px;'></a>";
```